# If $G$ is a group with, then the subgroup of $S_n$ constructed in the proof of Cayley’s theorem is a transitive subgroup of $S_G$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

I'm new to group theory and have some struggles to show the the question. Here, a subgroup $H\subset S_n$ is called transitive if for every $\{i,j\}\subset\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ there is a $\tau\in H$ with $\tau(i) = j$ and Cayley's theorem says that every group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_G$.

We can define a homomorphism $\varphi : G\to S_G$ and know the fact that $G$ is isomorphic to $\varphi(G)$. So I think that we need to show that $\varphi(G)$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_G$ (if I'm correct so far) and I cannot progress anymore. Can you help me to show this or if my approach is wrong, correct it please.

Comment: What is the homomorphism $\phi : G \rightarrow S_G?$ If I had to guess, probably $\phi(g) = L_g$, where $L_g : G \rightarrow G$ is defined by $L_g(x) = gx$ or something like that (I might have messed up something, you need to be careful here so that it's actually a homomorphism).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to chase the proof of Cayley's theorem.  If your group $G$ is
$$
\{e=g_1, g_2, \ldots, g_n\}
$$
then we have the permutation $\sigma_k$ induced by $g_k$ which respects the permutation on the subscripts obtained by left-multipying by $g_k$.  So, if $g_kg_i = g_j$ then $\sigma_k(i)=j$.  Then $g_k \mapsto \sigma_k$ is an isomorphism from $G$ to the subgroup $\{\sigma_k \mid k = 1, 2, \ldots, n\}\subseteq S_n$.

Now the result is clear:  if you want to know which permutation maps $i$ to $j$, you just use the subscript $k$ corresponding to $g_jg_i^{-1}$.  This is some element $g_k \in G$, and by definition $\sigma_k(i)=j$.

Edit:  I see that I did this in $S_n$ and not $S_G$, but it's the same idea:  the equation $xi=j$ can always be solved for $x \in G$.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a good idea to keep well-separated in the argument the symmetric groups $S_G$ and $S_n$. Said $\varphi$ Cayley's embedding of $G$ into $S_G$, the subgroup $\varphi(G)\le S_G$ is transitive because, for every $g,h\in G$, we get $\varphi_{hg^{-1}}(g)=h$: so, for every $g,h\in G$, there's an element of $
\varphi(G)$ (namely $\varphi_{hg^{-1}}$), which carries $g$ to $h$.

Now, to plug this all into $S_n$, you have to take a *bijection* $f\colon G\to\{1,\dots,n\}$ and define the isomorphism (prove it) $\psi_f\colon S_G\to S_n$ via $\sigma\mapsto f\sigma f^{-1}$. Then $\psi_f(\varphi(G))$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_n$ (isomorphic to $G$), because, for every $i,j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&(\psi_f(\varphi_{f^{-1}(j)(f^{-1}(i))^{-1}}))(i)=j \\
\end{alignat}